# Issue with REST API URL containing a plus sign

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud

We are having an issue with our primaryKeys (email address) containing the plus (+) sign. Here is some example code from a node-fuel implementation for reference:

```
fuel({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:myKey/rows/UserId:myemail@gmail.com',
    json: true,
    body: myjsonObject
}, function (error, request, body) {
    if(error){
        console.log("There was an error");
    } else {
        //handle response
   }
});
```

This code works as expected. However, changing the UserId to myemail+test@gmail.com fails silently with a 404. (I've tried substituting the plus sign for %2b and have tried encodeURIComponent(UserId) end even tried uri: instead of url: all with the same results) Further, setting "UserId":"myemail+test@gmail.com" in the jsonObject essentially makes the record inaccessible through the API.

Comment: not too familiar with FuelAPI but looking through their docs I found this method : https://code.exacttarget.com/api/address-validateemail validateemail. Where are u making the callout from if it is salesforce can u check if the UserId.contains('+') and replace it with ('').

Comment: I actually forget to add an exacttarget tag to my post (just edited), but this is where exacttarget is directing their Q&A now :/

Comment: @Akrikos: ExactTarget is beginning to be more active on this site. See http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/505/exacttarget-add-to-sf-se-or-spin-up-a-new-se

Comment: @rao: I cannot replace '+' with '' as myemail+test@gmail.com is not the same as myemailtest@gmail.com. Gmail disregards everything after the '+' when delivering messages. ValidateEmail validates so long as I use %2b instead of '+'

Comment: Thanks for point that out @MikeChale. I've removed my comment and deleted my guess post as others felt it was unhelpful.

Comment: No worries, @Akrikos; the site is growing and expanding so it's a relatively new change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does look like that service does not support passing plus signs in the key value however there is a very similar route for rowset which I tested and can confirm that it does support it since the keys are passed in the request body instead of the URL.  More details on this route can be found at:

https://code.exacttarget.com/api/dataevents-rowset

Comment: This works perfectly.. Thanks! On a side note, is there a limit on the number of objects I can throw at rowset in one call?

Comment: I don't believe there is any limit here outside of scaling in large numbers, but even then it shouldn't be too terrible, and you can also do the async version.